# google chart error without message or error id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

Like i mentioned in the title i get an error in the chart but no mesage so i cant fix it. Also the chart is function well. Here is a picture of the chart. it looks fine and the onhover and onclick functions of the chart are working too.

[image: error pic]

Here is my JS for the chart. The tabs may be a bit weird because of the way im inserting it in to stackoverflow. Its almost the same as the example charts. I have added listener to check if window size changes and i have a few buttons on the page that give the json call a value to query with.finally there is a function to get $_GET variables.

```
var clicked = false;
var nr = "";
$(function () {

        $('button[id^="chart_button"]').on('click', function (e) {
        clicked = true;
        nr = $(this).attr('id');
        drawChart();
        });

    //check window size
    if (document.addEventListener){
        window.addEventListener("resize", drawChart);
    }else if (document.attachEvent){
        window.attachEvent("onresize", drawChart);
    }else{
        window.resize = drawChart;
    }
});

function getstart(){
    if(clicked){
        return $('#'+nr).attr('value');
    }
    return $('#tabbuttongroup').children().first().attr('value');
}

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "modules/Forecast/models/getForecastChart.php",
        data: {
            id: getQueryVariable('record'),
            start_date: getstart()
        },
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var mydata = $.parseJSON(jsonData);

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn("datetime", "Date");
    data.addColumn("number", "Actual Amount");
    data.addColumn("number", "Forecast Amount");
    data.addColumn("number", "Actual Price");
    data.addColumn("number", "Forecast Price");

    for(var i = 0; i < mydata['forecast'].length; i++){
        var datesplit = String(mydata['forecast'][i][2]).split('-');
        var date = new Date(datesplit[0], datesplit[1]-1, datesplit[2]);

        data.addRow([
            date,
            Number(mydata['actual'][i][5]),
            Number(mydata['forecast'][i][5]),
            Number(mydata['actual'][i][6]),
            Number(mydata['forecast'][i][6])
        ]);
    }

    var options = {
        bars: 'vertical',
        hAxis: {
            title: "Date",
            gridlines: {
                count: -1,
                units: {
                    days: {
                        format: ["dd MMM"]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            format: 'decimal'
        },
        colors: ['#00AAFF', '#0088FF', '#EEDD55', '#EEBB55']
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
        for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                if (pair[0] == variable) {
                        return pair[1];
                }
        }
        alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
}
```

Comment: there is none that i can see. thats the problem. i get the red bar with error while there is no error.

Comment: So what is not happening? You haven't given any information about what you expect to happen

Comment: all that im expecting is happening so thats good. But there is one thing too much thats happening and that is the error(see picture). I wouldnt mind it but other people who see it will. Thats why i want a way to fix if broken or a way to remove that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can listen for the `'error'` event on the chart, which *may* provide more details

`google.visualization.events.addListener(chartInstance, 'error', handler);`

`handler` will receive an argument with two properties, `id` & `message`

you can then `removeError` using the `id` or simply `removeAll` using the chart container

also, when using *Material* charts, you should convert the options...
`google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options)`

(note the difference in the gridlines)

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var mydata = {forecast: [
      [new Date(2016,04,31), 5, 6, 7, 8],
      [new Date(2016,05,01), 4, 8, 9, 8],
      [new Date(2016,05,02), 8, 4, 0, 6],
      [new Date(2016,05,03), 2, 2, 1, 3]
    ]};

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn("datetime", "Date");
    data.addColumn("number", "Actual Amount");
    data.addColumn("number", "Forecast Amount");
    data.addColumn("number", "Actual Price");
    data.addColumn("number", "Forecast Price");

    for(var i = 0; i < mydata['forecast'].length; i++){
        data.addRow([
            mydata['forecast'][i][0],
            mydata['forecast'][i][1],
            mydata['forecast'][i][2],
            mydata['forecast'][i][3],
            mydata['forecast'][i][4]
        ]);
    }

    var options = {
        bars: 'vertical',
        hAxis: {
            title: "Date",
            gridlines: {
                count: -1,
                units: {
                    days: {
                        format: ["dd MMM"]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            format: 'decimal'
        },
        colors: ['#00AAFF', '#0088FF', '#EEDD55', '#EEBB55']
    };

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(container);

    // throw error for testing
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      throw new Error('Test Google Error');
    });

    // listen for error
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', function (err) {
      // check error
      console.log(err.id, err.message);

      // remove error
      google.visualization.errors.removeError(err.id);

      // remove all errors
      google.visualization.errors.removeAll(container);
    });

    // convert options
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thnx mate, worked like a charm. There are no error messages in the console either so i dont know why an error was thrown but it work fine now.

Comment: @WhiteHat  Thanks! Works perfectly. Q: why do we need to remove errors?

Comment: it isn't necessary to remove the error, but i typically like to handle them myself, rather than having google's red error box displayed to the user...

Answer (score 0):

Why not *KISS* hiding the element with css, like that:

````
[id^="google-visualization-errors"] {
    display: none;
}```
````